# fmod function from math.h library in C not working correctly?

Tags: c, math, gcc, cygwin, modulo

Ok, so hopefully I do not look like an idiot from asking this question...as it is quite basic, but my brain is either on vacation or something is indeed wrong.

So `-4 % 5` or `-4 mod 5` should equal `1` correct? Why is it that the `fmod` function from the math.h library returns `-4` when you use it, i.e `fmod(-4, 5)` returns `-4` instead of `1`. I'm using the `gcc compiler via cygqin` if that is any help as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it should return 1 not -4 by definition of mod.

Comment: agreed, so is it something wrong with the function or possibly my compiler...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `%` operator is the *remainder* operator, not modulo.  The `fmod` function is also the floating point *remainder*, not modulo.  In this case, they have selected to round -4/5 toward 0 to an integer.

Comment: Alright they should rename the function then i guess...Thanks a lot tho!

Comment: @SabashanRagavan: The important mistake you made is guessing at the interface contract of a function (admittedly, based on a misleading name) rather than reading the specification, which would clearly have explained the required result.

Answer (score 1):

POSIX [states](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fmod.html):

> ```
>     #include <math.h>
>     double fmod(double x, double y);
> ```
>
> These functions shall return the value `x - i * y`, for some integer `i` such that,
>   if `y` is non-zero, the result has the same sign as `x` and magnitude less than the 
>   magnitude of `y`.

In the case of `fmod(-4,5)`, since the result must have the same size of `x`, it will be negative, and `i` cannot be less than zero.  If `i` were to be one, the result would be larger than `y`, so `i` must be zero, and the result of `-4.0` is correct.